# Nokia 7.2 running slow with Android One version 9

Tags: 9.0-pie, android-one, lagging

I have Nokia 7.2 which is running Android One version 9. Since 2-3 weeks there I have observed a visible sluggishness in my phone. For e.g. it takes 1-2 seconds when I turn on/off WiFi or mobile data. Below are some of the steps I have taken to resolve this but none have succeeded so far.

1. Deleted all the unused few apps
2. Reduced animation to 0.5x from Developer Options
3. Periodically verified `Settings > Battery` to check any misbehaving app. But it always shows 'Phone has typical background battery usage'
4. Made sure all the apps and Android is updated as and when an update is received. The current security patch is for 5 Dec 2019.

The sluggishness seems to restricted to the Android functionality itself like unlocking the phone, turning on the camera. The apps themselves run fine once they are opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some reports in [Nokia Community](https://community.phones.nokia.com/discussion/54608/nokia-7-2-problems-after-android-9-pie-v1-390-update) that the most recent MR update (December 2nd update) release to the Nokia 7.2 has caused some lagginess for a number of users. You will need to wait for Nokia to push a release which fixes this.

My Nokia 7.2 has been working normally. So, not all users are impacted. And some users already tried with a hard reset with zero luck.